# Convert SelectList to List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

How can i convert SelectList to a List() ?

Code:

```
Session["Employers"] = new SelectList(employers.DistinctBy(i => i.empId), "EmpId", "EmpName");
```

Comment: And you can't do `ToList()`?

Comment: A list of what?  For what purpose?  If you *must* store data in session (and you probably shouldn't, but I suppose there are *some* reasons to) then you should store the backing data (in this case `employers`) and not the UI elements.  UI elements should be rendered in the view and only in the view.

Comment: I look forward to cleaning up your code someday.

Comment: Try `Session["Employers"] = (new SelectList(employers.DistinctBy(i => i.empId), "EmpId", "EmpName")).Items.ToList();`

Comment: Why are you storing a list in `Session`? Is it for caching purposes?

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `ToList()` at the end.

```
Session["Employers"] = new SelectList(employers.DistinctBy(i => i.empId), "EmpId", "EmpName").ToList();
```